# Add something to all rows starting in excel sheet

Tags: excel

I have an excel sheet with >2000 records with two columns.
I want to add

```
{"<first_col_data>",
```

and

```
"<sec_col_data>"},
```

to all the rows, and save to a text file. I mean adding the curly brace, double-quotes and comma.
e.g.
data.xls =>

```
      A    |   B 
----------------------------------
title_add  | ADDING SOMETHING
title_list | LISTING SOMETHING
```

output text file data.txt =>

```
{"title_add","ADDING SOMETHING"},
{"title_list","LISTING SOMETHING"},
```

How do I do that? I have no idea of macros or functions.

Thanks for your help....

Comment: Are you just doing this once or will you need to do it often?

Comment: once for now. in future may be some other pattern requirement comes!

Comment: Then I would suggest @Jook's idea below - simple and quick!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On a second Sheet simply use this formulas, then save the sheet:

```
 Sheet2!A1=CONCATENATE("{""",Sheet1!A1,""",""",Sheet1!B1,"""}")
```

this should result into:

```
 {"title_add","ADDING SOMETHING"}
```

and this is my original formula, which created the result above:

```
 =VERKETTEN("{""";A1;""",""";B1;"""}")
```

My other solution (as a one time quickie) would be using Notepad++ to find/replace/insert after saving the *xls* as as *csv* or *txt*. Or AWK, if this is a regular thing.

You could of course do this with a macro, maybe someone else is so nice to provide one for you, but as you don't have any idea of macros, I wouldn't even recommend it, until you have some idea ;)

Comment: You mean to put it in the second sheet of the workbook? In the function bar where we can edit the field data? and then what?
[PS sorry for over-asking. am a noob in that]

Comment: Yes, put the formula `=CONCATENATE("{""",Sheet1!A1,""",""",Sheet1!B1,"""}")` on any other worksheet of your workbook into cell A1 - assuming your original data is on a worksheet named `Sheet1`. Then copy it down, then just stay on the sheet and use `save as` to save as txt.

Comment: Thank you Jook! It was alien to me but you helped, and I am more than grateful. I think time is nigh to learn some Excel stuff.